# "To highlight" vs To marker"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which one is more common in use in the following context of learning with books?

> To highlight
>
> To marker

In addition I've tried to turn the verb "marker" into past tens form (markered) but Google Chrome marks it as mistake.

[image]

Comment: ***To marker** [some text]* isn't really a valid "verbification". It would be understood, but unless you were obviously a native speaker just "playing with language", most people would probably think you didn't know English very well. So trust Chrome, and avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression you may be looking for is "to mark up", which has a number of meanings, one of which is:

> [**to mark up**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mark+up) (verb): to make changes, notes, and corrections on a document

It's not quite appropriate in this case since you aren't making *changes* to the document, but simply *marking* relevant important passages so that when you (presumably) review the text later you can just read those and skip the rest.

So you can either use the simple "to mark", as in

> While studying he *marked* the passages that he thought were important

or instead "to highlight" since this common and perfectly natural modern English:

> When studying, many like to *highlight* important passages in their books -- but I've never found this a very effective strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As you said "to mark up" is not relevant to my context, and that's why I don't understand why did you open with the assuming that this is the idiomatic expression that I'm looking for.

Comment: @AdorableSpectacle  I should have said "It's probably the expression you're **thinking of**.  I assumed you heard it somewhere, but misunderstood it as "to marker" instead of "to mark up", since these sound very similar.